# how to correctly substract values in x86 64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to implement strcmp using assembly, I don't understand why the return value is not as expected:

```
global  _ft_strcmp

section .text

_ft_strcmp:
    cmp     [rdi], byte 0
    je      _done
    cmp     [rsi], byte 0
    je      _done
    cmpsb
    je      _ft_strcmp

_done:
    dec     rdi
    dec     rsi
    xor     rax, rax
    mov     rax , [rdi]
    sub     rax , [rsi]
    ret
```

I'm testing it using the C code below:

```
int  ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2);

int main()
{
    char *x = "A";
    char *y = "B";
    printf("%i %i", ft_strcmp(x, y), strcmp(x, y));
}
```

The output is: `-1759707137 -1`

It looks like an underflow but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you expect `mov rax, [rdi]` to do exactly?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen store the ascii value of the character pointed by rdi in rax

Comment: `rax` is a 64bit register so it will take a 64bit value with `mov`, not 8bit

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I tried to use `al`, the return value is 255 which is still false

Comment: 255 is the unsigned version of -1. Calculate with AL, then sign extend to RAX

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: You need to sign- or zero-extend both characters and *then* do 32-bit (or 64-bit if you want) subtraction, to unambiguously determine which one was larger based on just the sign of the sub result (without considering OF).  This is why signed compares need to look at OF and SF, not just SF.

Comment: why dont you compare generated code of the original strcmp with your one? https://godbolt.org/z/mSWhCQ

Comment: @P__J__ that's a handy tool, thanks